# What can I do with bluetooth connection between Mac Book Pro and iPod Touch?

Tags: macos, bluetooth, ipod

First time apple computer owner here, and also first time bluetooth-anything user.  I have a 2nd gen iPod Touch and established a bluetooth connection with my new mac book pro.  But, it wasn't clear to me what, if anything, I can do with that connection.  Can I get my ipod to automatically sync over bluetooth when in range?  Are there any other neat tricks/utilities that take advantage of this combination?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what profiles the iPod touch supports. I think that it only has A2DP bluetooth support, which is intended for high quality cordless audio headsets, and speakers basically means that you can use it as an audio input source.

I don't think it has the profiles needed for data exchanging, but I may be mistaken.

*correction*

Actually, it says on the apple site - http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3647 that it does support the PAN profile, and the AV remote control profile. I guess this means that you can use IP networking over BT, and use the a wireless remote control device with it too. You might need to install suitable software on the ipod first.

Answer (score -1):

A bit late but you could use the app "remote" to use your ipod touch 2G and 3G as a remote for itunes. But that syncs over wifi instead of bluetoth...